# How to implement full vertical rotation around the object in OrbitControls?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like it to keep rotating all around the object. But I can't set minPolarAngle/maxPolarAngle(When I set it to (+-)Infinity rotation is not working).

Can the min and max PolarAngles in OrbitControls  be (+-)Infinity?

```
// How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
// Range is 0 to Math.PI radians.
this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians

// How far you can orbit horizontally, upper and lower limits.
// If set, must be a sub-interval of the interval [ - Math.PI, Math.PI ].
this.minAzimuthAngle = -Infinity; // radians
this.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity; // radians
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how orbit controls work. By design it's going to use polar angles and an up vector i believe, thus always keeping the camera sort of aligned with the world / horizon. You should look into trackball controls which are designed to just keep rotating.

Comment: Zoom is not working with TrackballControls and orthographic camera

Comment: not sure about that one, but the rotation fits the scenario you described, shouldnt be that hard to implement zoom or combine the two controllers? With some experimentation you could even try nesting them, have zoom enabled on one, rotation on the other, combine in a parent object, or copy the values once processed etc.